# ProgressBar in UpdateProgress keeps expiring before the data is fetched

Tags: asp.net, gridview, progress-bar, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have a `GridView` which shows some data and has a `Button` in the last column that combines the value of the 3 other columns.
I was able to refresh the `GridView` easily just by calling this Function `GridData` in the `rowCommand`.

```
    protected void GridviewProcess_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "More")
            {
                objENT = new ENT();

                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                Label locCode = (Label)GridviewProcess.Rows[index].FindControl("lbl0");
                Label SurveyNo = (Label)GridviewProcess.Rows[index].FindControl("lbl2");
                Button Combine = (Button)GridviewProcess.Rows[index].FindControl("btnCombine");

                Combine.Enabled = false;
                objENT.LocationCode = locCode.Text;
                objENT.SurveyNumber = SurveyNo.Text;
                objENT.ProcType = "CREATECUSTOMER";
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = BLL.CdCustomer(objENT);


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Some Error occurred Please refresh the page')", true);

        }
        finally
        {
            Griddata();
        }

    private void Griddata()
    {
        objENT.ProcType = "PAGEGRIDDATA";
        DataSet ds = BLL.ProcessGrid(objENT);
        string check = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TOTAL_CUSTOMER"].ToString();


        GridviewProcess.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ViewState["Grid"] = ds.Tables[0];
        GridviewProcess.DataBind();
    }
```

After,I added this `ProgressBar`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2">
                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                <img src="images/progress_bar.gif" style="max-width: 250px" />
                            </ProgressTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdateProgress>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridviewProcess" AllowPaging="true"   CssClass="GridHeader" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"  PagerSettings-PreviousPageText="<-Prev  " PagerSettings-Visible="true" PagerSettings-NextPageText="  Next->"
                                     PagerSettings-FirstPageText="<=FirstPage  " PagerSettings-LastPageText="  LastPage=>"     PagerStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
                                     OnPageIndexChanging="GridviewProcess_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="12" OnRowDataBound="GridviewProcess_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridviewProcess_RowCommand" runat="server" Style="text-align: center"  Width="99%"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Customers" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCCC">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TOTAL_CUSTOMER") %>'>

                                                </asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnCombine" CssClass="btn-primary btn" Text="Combine"
                                                    CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" CommandName="More"
                                                    Style="padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px" runat="server" />

                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>

                                </asp:GridView>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddi" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The `ProgressBar` will show but after the function `GridData()`{} is called it wont refresh the `GridView`.
I can see the changes only after,I refresh the whole page.
I don't understand whats going wrong... 
I don't have any `JS` or `CSS` used for this `ProgressBar`..(Is that the problem?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution to the Problem on SO questions

[UpdateProgress Timed Out before data could be processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318213/problems-using-updateprogress)

Actual problem was :
I have a button on my ASP.NET page, which fetches some data from my database and displays it on a `GridView`.

This process takes a while, so I thought I'll add an updateprogress `AJAX` control. Now when I click the button, the `UpdateProgress` Image shows up and data is being fetched from my database successfully (I checked this from some logs that I have in my DB). But there are 2 issues:

The `UpdateProgress` image shows only for about 2 minutes. But my `ButtonClick` event takes about 5 minutes to complete. Basically the `UpdateProgress`stops showing up even before my task is complete, which defeats its purpose.

As I found this in one of the SO Answers

As per issue  most likely it is ajax timing out. Default timeout is 90 seconds. To increase that use `ScriptManager's` `AsyncPostBackTimeout` property:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="400">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

If `AJAX` call is timing out, controls on the page might not work correctly so increasing timeout might solve problem (2) as well.